# Setup method in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Are the operations in the setup method performed for every mapper? Can the results obtained in the setup method be used for all of the mappers?

Answer (score 2):

The operations of `setup()` method are performed on every `Mapper`. As Mapper's are share nothing the results obtained by the `setup()` can only be used by that particular `Mapper` which invoked the `setup()` method.